# csscomb for sublime node.js error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I tried to install *csscomb* for *sublime text*. It's showing this error

'node' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

i was tring to execute csscomb by pressing shift+ctrl+c. my operating system is windows 8.1.

What should I do?

Comment: You need to give us much more information before anyone can help. Do you have node installed? What is the full path to the `node` or `nodejs` command? Is it on your `PATH`? What operating system are you using? What were you doing when you got this error? What is the **full** text of the error? Please [edit] your question to add all of this information.

Comment: @MattDMoyes, node.js is in the c:\program files\nodejs folder. but, how do i set the path?

Comment: Please edit your question with the answers to all of the questions I asked, and I should be able to help you.

Comment: Are you using CSScomb or CSScomb JS? CSScomb is deprecated, and should not be used.

Comment: CSScomb JS. i installed it via the package control...

Comment: @MattDMo prettify is working fine though

Answer (score 0):

Check if path with node binary (`C:\Program Files\nodejs\`) is added to your Path Environment Variable.

You can modify Path Environment Variable by going through My Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings and find it on System variables list. In case of any problems, you can easily find **[posts like this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)** describing how to do it.

Comment: it's there. still it's not working. where am i supposed to install nodejs?